# Find most recent price in price list

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a table with Item, Price and Price Date columns.  What I need to do is filter out only the old prices, showing only the most recent price for each item. I am using MS Access 2007 and need to reference the most updated price in some VBA I am writing, and in my research I cannot find a way to programmaticly access pivot table data for customer pricing elsewhere in the DB.

## Example:

Table

Item | Price | Price Date

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help here

Comment: select dbo_itemprice_mst_all.*
    from dbo_itemprice_mst_all
    where dbo_itemprice_mst_all.effect_date = (select 
    max(dbo_itemprice_mst_all.effect_date) from dbo_itemprice_mst_all as dbo_itemprice_mst_all        where dbo_itemprice_mst_all.item = dbo_itemprice_mst_all.item);

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.pricedate = (select max(t2.pricedate)
                     from t as t2
                     where t2.item = t.item
                    );
```

Comment: I used the above and it only returns two rows.  Perhaps I've buggered something up and updated the post to include the code.

Comment: Your code (1) looks very little like this code and (2) doesn't match the data in your question.

Answer (score 0):

One option uses a subquery to find the most recent price for each item:

```
SELECT t1.Item, t1.Price, t1.PriceDate
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE t1.PriceDate = (SELECT MAX(t2.PriceDate) FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.Item = t1.Item);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more efficient than using MAX()-function:

```
SELECT Item, Price, PriceDate
FROM customer_pricing t1
WHERE NOT EXITS(
    SELECT *
    FROM customer_pricing t2
    WHERE t1.item = t2.item
    AND t1.PriceDate < t2.PriceDate
)
```

Comment: Thank you this solved the problem and its quite quick.

Comment: @dewey . . . Do you have any evidence that this is faster than using `max()`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was by @dewey and was

```
SELECT t1.item, t1.unit_price1, t1.effect_date, t1.site_ref
FROM dbo_itemprice_mst_all AS t1
WHERE (((t1.site_ref)="MED" Or (t1.site_ref)="CRD") AND ((Exists (SELECT *
    FROM dbo_itemprice_mst_all t2
    WHERE t1.item = t2.item
    AND t1.effect_date < t2.effect_date
    ))=False))
ORDER BY t1.item;
```

Comment: Take some time and read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers/251399#251399 If an answer solved your problem you should accept it by clicking the checkmark at the left.